# Phenomenon causing Voltage in Batteries

Tags: potential, voltage, physical-chemistry, batteries, electrochemistry

I have a simple question: you can think of a charged particle as a particle with mass, and hence there will be an electric field surrounding the charge, which causes electric potential energy (if there is a charged particle within its field). However, how does this work within a circuit? How can a battery have electric potential difference (if I'm not wrong, this quantity is known as voltage) that causes the movement of electrons?

I was looking at some electrochemistry that day, and was wondering if the two terminals of a battery were really electrodes, and the reactivity difference would cause a reduction in one electrode and oxidation in the other, leading to the transfer of electrons. Even still, what is the underlying physical phenomenon that causes this transfer of electrons?

Comment: try reading https://www.science.org.au/curious/technology-future/batteries